# When to use 'Break' in For loop?

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, conditional-statements, break

I have various pages, each of them contain some number of arrays,

For example:

Page 1 contains only 2 arrays:

```
$textual_button[1] = "I am a long character";
$textual_button[2] = "I am also a long character";
```

Page 2 contains 20 arrays:

```
$textual_button[1] = "I am a long character";
...
...
$textual_button[19] = "I am also a long character";
$textual_button[20] = "I am also a very long character";
```

Therefore, I want to check a certain condition in the first 15 arrays (Which may exists - like in page 2 , or may not - like at page 1, which contians just 2)

I want to apply some styling classes named `small` and `big` ,or no class at all, depending on two conditions:

1. By default, do not set any class.
2. If an image exists in the array, check the string length of the first 15 arrays.
   if all of them are shorter than 11 characters, set a `big` class. otherwise, set a `small` class.
3. No matter if an image exists or no, if at least one array out of the first 15, has 14 or more characters, then set a `small` class (and overwrite `big` class if it was set earlier)

This is the code, I'm not sure when and how to use `break`:

```
$class = "nothing"; //default class

if (in_array(true, $image)) { // If there's any image in array :

    $class = "small"; // by default, apply small class 

        for($x = 1;$x <= 15;$x++){  // check on array 1 to 15
            if (strlen((string)$textual_button[$x]) <= 11) {  // if all textual string are  less or equal to 11 characters , make them big
            $class = "big";  
            };
        break; // Is this necessary?
        } 
}

 // In general, no matter if there's an image in array:

for($x = 1;$x <= 15;$x++){  // check on array 1 to 15
    if (strlen((string)$textual_button[$x]) >= 14) {  // if even one textual string is 14 or more, make all of them small.
      $class = "small";
    };
    break; // When is it necessary?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`break` breaks out of the loop so in both cases, your loop will only run once, or the first iteration, and stop then.

So no, you should not use `break` here as you have already limited the number of iterations to 15.

`break` could be useful (there are other methods...) if you were looping over *all* elements in the array, keep a counter and then check if the counter is 15 to break out of the loop.

Note that you probably want a `foreach` loop anyway instead of a  `for` loop as a `for` loop with 15 iterations will lead to php warnings when there are less than 15 elements in your array.

What I would personally do in your case, is slice the array to a maximum of 15 elements (less when there are less...) and to a `foreach` on that.

On last thing: You are overwriting your `$class` variable in the loop so it is probably not going to do what you expect it to. You should probably set a boolean to `false` if any of the elements does not meet your condition and then set the class according to that boolean *after* the loop.

In general, if *any* needs to match, you could use break but if *all* need to match, you always need to finish the loop.

Comment: On page 1 (with 2 arrays), When I don't use `break`, the class `big` was set, even though all the arrays were longer than 11 characters. So i thought that maybe it is beacuse it is trying to check for non existent array (3-15), and since it doesn't exists, length is considered `0`, and it applies the big class. So I thought break would check if the condition was met at least once and then avoid running the loop again. So where does stopping or not stopping when a condition is met fits in? I'm still confused. How to do this from scratch?

Comment: How can I count the number of arrays to make it less when there are less? 
Also, does break means that when a condition is met the first time, the loop will end? or it isn't related to break. is it related for foreach?

Comment: @rockyraw Just use `array_slice($arr, 0, 15)` and use a `foreach` to loop over that.

Comment: I don't get it though. If break always breaks the loops, why would anyone want to use a loop with break, in the first place, if it is not really going to loop?

Comment: @rockyraw Like I said, if you test in your loop and *any* needs to match, you can break as soon as you find a match.

Comment: Can you provide a code example? `$sliced_array = array_slice($textual_button, 0, 15);` returns `Array`. shouldn't it be `2` if I have two arrays on page 1? shouldn't I use `count($textual_button)`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this

```
$class = "nothing"; //default class

if (in_array(true, $image)) { // If there's any image in array :

    $class = "small"; // by default, apply small class 

        for($x = 1;$x <= 15;$x++){  // check on array 1 to 15
            if (strlen((string)$textual_button[$x]) <= 11) {  // if all textual string are  less or equal to 11 characters , make them big
            $class = "big";
            };
            else {
            $class = "small";
            break;
            }
        } 
}

 // In general, no matter if there's an image in array:

for($x = 1;$x <= 15;$x++){  // check on array 1 to 15
    if (strlen((string)$textual_button[$x]) >= 14) {  // if even one textual string is 14 or more, make all of them small.
      $class = "small";
      break;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Could You have meant something like this?

```
<?php

    $class      = "nothing"; 
    if (in_array(true, $image)) {    
        $class  = "small"; 
        for($x = 1;$x <= 15;$x++){  
            if (strlen( (string)$textual_button[$x] ) <= 11) { 
                $class = "big";
                // BREAK OUT OF THE LOOP INSIDE THE IF CLAUSE SINCE YOU HAVE REACHED YOUR GOAL
                // WHICH IS : THE LENGTH OF $textual_button[$x] IS LESS THAN OR EQUAL TO 11  
                break;
            }else{
                // NO NEED FOR AN EXTRA LOOP SINCE IT IS ESSENTIALLY THE SAME LOOP
                // JUST DO WHATEVER YOU WISH WITHIN THE ELSE CLAUSE...
                // THAT IS IF: THE LENGTH OF $textual_button[$x] IS GREATER THAN OR EQUAL TO 14  
                // AGAIN BREAK OUT OF THE LOOP INSIDE THE ELSE CLAUSE SINCE YOU HAVE REACHED YOUR GOAL
                $class = "small";   
                break;             
            }             
        }
    }
```

> Or something like this?

```
    $class      = "nothing";
    if (in_array(true, $image)) {
        $class  = "small";
        for($x = 1;$x <= 15;$x++){
            if (strlen( (string)$textual_button[$x] ) <= 11) {
                $class = "big";
                // BREAK OUT OF THE LOOP INSIDE THE IF CLAUSE SINCE YOU HAVE REACHED YOUR GOAL
                // WHICH IS : THE LENGTH OF $textual_button[$x] IS LESS THAN OR EQUAL TO 11
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    for($x = 1;$x <= 15;$x++){  // check on array 1 to 15
        if (strlen( (string)$textual_button[$x]) >= 14 ) {
            // AGAIN BREAK OUT OF THE LOOP INSIDE THE ELSE CLAUSE SINCE YOU HAVE REACHED YOUR GOAL
            // THAT IS IF: THE LENGTH OF $textual_button[$x] IS GREATER THAN OR EQUAL TO 14
            $class = "small";
            break;
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In both of your cases, only once `for` loop will occur because you're breaking it without checking anything. If you want to check whether all array elements meet criteria, you should put `break` inside of `if` conditional:

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 15; $x++) {
    if (strlen((string)$textual_button[$x]) <= 11) {
        $class = "big";
        break;  
    };
 }
```

In this case, if any element in array is shorter than 11 symbols, `$class` will become `big` and `for` loop will stop executing. This will be true for second `for` as well if you change the code similarly to first example.